# Database error in PHP

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO reg ('name','email','add',c_no,'user_name','pass','mess')
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[add]','$_POST[number]','$_POST[user]','$_POST[pass]','$_POST[comment]')";
```

The error I get is:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name','email','add',c_no,'user_name','pass','mess') VALUES ('admin','swapni' at line 1

Comment: 1. You have a SQL injection vulnerability; 2. You shouldn't store unhashed passwords in your database. Learn about password hashing, salting and bcrypt.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `'` sign in column names, instead use backtick ` or skip it if field name is not reserved keyword.

Also instead of putting `$_POST` variables into sql, read about prepared statements and always check input data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

And your field names are encapsulated with ', they should be with ` or nothing if they don't match MySQL reserved words.

Third mysql_* are deprecated: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Fourth: `"...('$_POST['something']','..."` is very bad practice, I don't think that it'll work in the latest PHP and you should strongly consider to write it like `"...('" . $text_to_insert . "','..."`

Solution to all of this problems in MySQLi:

```
$db=new mysqli("server","username","password","database");
$insert_stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO reg (name,email,add,c_no,user_name,pass,mess) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$insert_stmt->bindParam("sssisss",$_POST["name"],$_POST["email"],$_POST["add"],$_POST["c_no"],$_POST["user_name"],$_POST["pass"],$_POST["mess"]);
$is_successful=$insert_stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Column names should be encapsulated with backticks, not quotes.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO reg (`name`,`email`,`add`,`c_no`,`user_name`,`pass`,`mess`)
VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[add]','$_POST[number]','$_POST[user]','$_POST[pass]','    $_POST[comment]')";
```

Comment: Backticks are only needed when using reserved keywords as column names.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i am using between operator for the fetching data from date to date.

Query is....

`SELECT`customer`.*,`feedback`.*,`feedback`.`id`as fid
FROM (`feedback`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN`customer`ON`customer`.`feedbackID`=`feedback`.`id
`WHERE`feedback`.`spa_id`=  '1'
AND`feedback`.`Overall_rating`!=  ''
AND`feedback`.`fb_date`BETWEEN "2014-06-01" and "2015-10-30"`

using this query i am unable to fetch the data for the date "2015-10-30"

Thank You.

Answer (score -4):

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add']);
$c_no = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['c_no']);
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$mess = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mess']);

$sql= "INSERT INTO reg (`name`,`email`,`add`,`c_no`,`user_name`,`pass`,`mess`) 
VALUES($name,$email,$add,$c_no,$user_name,$pass,$mess)";
```

Comment: You make the same mistake again, putting the field name in ' '!

Comment: Ok, let's ignore it's stupid to use `$_POST` in queries. PHP will not allow using `"` or `'` inside string when accessing arrays.

Comment: You've quoted the `$_POST` array index, which at least will suppress a warning, but left a SQL injection vulnerability in there. Ah yes, and you've broken out of the string using single quotes, rather than double quotes, and omitted the last string-closing quote after the bracket.